# How to count and mark the occurence of a sequence of a value in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I want to create a column C (based on B) which counts each beginning of a series from '100' in B. I have the following pandas data frame:

```
A B 
1 0
2 0
3 100
4 100
5 100
6 0
7 0
8 100
9 100
10 100
11 100
12 0
13 0
14 0
15 100
16 100
```

I want to create the following column C:

```
A C
1 0
2 0
3 1
4 1
5 1
6 0
7 0
8 2
9 2
10 2
11 2
12 0
13 0
14 0
15 3
16 3
```

This column C should count each series of 100s.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
df['C'] = (df['B'].shift(-1).eq(100) & df['B'].ne(100)).cumsum() * df['B'].eq(100)
print (df)
     A    B  C
0    1    0  0
1    2    0  0
2    3  100  1
3    4  100  1
4    5  100  1
5    6    0  0
6    7    0  0
7    8  100  2
8    9  100  2
9   10  100  2
10  11  100  2
11  12    0  0
12  13    0  0
13  14    0  0
14  15  100  3
15  16  100  3
```

**Details and explanation**:

1. Compare [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for `==`
2. Chain condition by `&` for `bitwise AND` with [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) for `!=` for Trues for one row before groups
3. Add [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) for counter
4. Replace values to `0` by multiple by compared column by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html)

---

```
df = df.assign(shifted = df['B'].shift(-1).eq(100),
               chained = df['B'].shift(-1).eq(100) & df['B'].ne(100),
               cumsum = (df['B'].shift(-1).eq(100) & df['B'].ne(100)).cumsum(),
               eq_100 = df['B'].eq(100),
               C = (df['B'].shift(-1).eq(100) & df['B'].ne(100)).cumsum() * df['B'].eq(100))
print (df)
     A    B  shifted  chained  cumsum  eq_100  C
0    1    0    False    False       0   False  0
1    2    0     True     True       1   False  0
2    3  100     True    False       1    True  1
3    4  100     True    False       1    True  1
4    5  100    False    False       1    True  1
5    6    0    False    False       1   False  0
6    7    0     True     True       2   False  0
7    8  100     True    False       2    True  2
8    9  100     True    False       2    True  2
9   10  100     True    False       2    True  2
10  11  100    False    False       2    True  2
11  12    0    False    False       2   False  0
12  13    0    False    False       2   False  0
13  14    0     True     True       3   False  0
14  15  100     True    False       3    True  3
15  16  100    False    False       3    True  3
```